# Can I suppress mypy errors in-line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I recently made the mistake of opening my `$PYTHONSTARTUP` file with `mypy` syntax checking enabled. As a result, I started getting this error:

```
startup.py|79 col 2 error| Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "HistoryPrompt", variable has type "str")
```

On line 79:

```
sys.ps1 = HistoryPrompt()
```

I immediately thought, "By Jove, `mypy`! You're entirely correct! And yet, that is exactly what I want to do, so you're also wrong!"

I went looking to see if there was some kind of "stub" for the `sys` module, but couldn't find anything. I'm guessing that `mypy` is determining the type by looking at the value stored in the variable (default is ">>> ", which is a `str`).

In reality, of course, the type needs to be the non-existant `typing.Stringifiable`, indicating an object that will respond to `str(x)`.

Having reached that dead end, I went looking for a way to tell `mypy` to suppress the error. So many of the other tools support `# noqa: xxx` that I figured there *must* be something, right?

Wrong. Or at least, I couldn't find it in my version, which is: `mypy 0.670`

So I devised a <s>hack</s> clever work-around:

```
import typing

# Work around mypy error: Incompatible types in assignment
suppress_mypy_error: typing.Any = HistoryPrompt()
sys.ps1 = suppress_mypy_error
```

My question is this: *Is there* a way to suppress this particular error in-line (best), or in `mypy.ini`, or by submitting a PR to `python/mypy`, or ...?

Comment: May help: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#spurious-errors-and-locally-silencing-the-checker

Comment: @Sraw I swear I spent a chunk of time poring over the docs. I guess I didn't scroll far enough down. :-(. I found a solution in `# type: ignore`. Write it up if you want the internet points...

Comment: Eh, why not. Wrote it up, and posted as Community Wiki.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To explicitly suppress MyPy on a specific line, add a comment of the form `# type: ignore`.

To suppress MyPy for an entire module, add the same comment at the top of the module.

Source: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#spurious-errors-and-locally-silencing-the-checker

Answer (score 11):

### Overview

I prefer to suppress mypy errors based on **2 things**:

- specific lines (your question), and
- specific error.

### Example

For example, the `# type: ignore [no-untyped-call]`:

```
# ignore mypy error because azure has broken type hints.
# See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/20083 (the issue is closed but the problem remains)
exception = azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError("Test") # type: ignore [no-untyped-call]
```

You can find out the "error code" (e.g. `no-untyped-call`) in the mypy output by configuring mypy with:

- in `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.mypy]
show_error_codes = true
```

- or in `mypy.ini`

```
[mypy]
show_error_codes = True
```

### Benefits

- Documentation in code: You can see exactly what error is being suppressed.
- You won't ignore other errors by mypy. Otherwise, that line could be a source of bugs in the future and mypy would not warn you.